# How to access application URL hosted in docker container?

Tags: docker

I hosted our application inside a docker container. When I run `docker ps` command, it gave info like below.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                        NAMES
6405daf98246        rdarukumalli/testapp-master   "/bin/bash"         4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:32797->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32796->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32795->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32794->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32793->9997/tcp   insane_poincare
```

I am trying to access this application from my machine with the following URLs. Nothing worked so far.

```
0.0.0.0:32795/testapp/login.jsp
0.0.0.0:8080/testapp/login.jsp
localhost:8080/testapp/login.jsp
localhost:32795/testapp/login.jsp
```

However, if i give the command `"curl http://localhost:8080/testapp/login.jsp"` inside bash of docker container, 
I can login page html is coming.

Can some one help me in understanding these URL mappings and what URL i need to use to access this login page outside docker container?

Comment: Did you use `--publish` argument on `docker run` to expose the ports of your app? Can you share the `docker run` command you're issuing?

Comment: This is run command i gave.  docker run -ti -p 8000 -p 443 -p 8443 -p 9997 -p 8080 -h "hostname" "imagename".    It doesn't have publish option.

Comment: Later, I ran the following mapping commands from my machine.                rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 8000 -> 127.0.0.1 port 32796
 rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 8080 -> 127.0.0.1 port 32795
 rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 8443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 32794
 rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 9997 -> 127.0.0.1 port 32793
 rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 32797

Comment: thanks, can you try `docker run -ti -p127.0.0.1:8080:8080 imagename`, then `curl http://localhost:8080/testapp/login.jsp` on your machine. Let's try with one port only first ;)

Comment: I gave the same command as you provided. Still same issue. I can access login page through curl command inside the bash from container. But outside the container, I am not able to access.

Comment: Is your development machine also your docker host?

Comment: Yes, In the same machine, I hosted docker.

Comment: Then this must be a networking issue with your firewall or `docker network`, please have a look at your firewall (maybe disable it a few time), and check your docker logs after a restart

Comment: @Ram, all what you did with rdr is not necessary. Indeed, maybe that is the problem

Comment: @Ram in docker run send one more option `--net=host` and then you'll be able to access login page via http://127.0.0.1:32795/testapp/login.jsp outside the container

Comment: I have the same issue. Has anyone figured it out? I see this question doesn't have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

Try `curl http://localhost:32795/testapp/login.jsp`.

Your `docker ps` shows that container's port 8080 is bound to external port 32795 : `[...] 0.0.0.0:32795->8080/tcp [...]`

Comment: I think the OP explicitly said that he tried `localhost:32795/testapp/login.jsp` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

docker ps command shows the running container which displays the port your application is running. On browser type http://localhost:54529/your_application_page. if you are running application locally, then this is the port which needs to be changed in browser to access container application.

[image]