# How to provide external url to docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am working on Docker Image, I am a beginner on Docker.
I have one Docker Image, but what I want to update my Docker Image as that my Docker Image should accept the one external URL like:- and 
start the further processing on it.

I do not have any clue how to do this, I am totally new on Docker and have only basic understanding of Docker.

Comment: Hi Ram, you and this [Ram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902919/how-to-access-application-url-hosted-in-docker-container) guy are asking very similar questions. Are you the same or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: No, we are not the same it is just a coincidence, can you please help me to resolve this Issue.

Comment: Sure. What kind of application do you have?

Comment: I have a Saas application, I have multiple micro services that can expose the URL dynamically.

Comment: I want to update one docker image which can accept any <url> as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

With docker-compose you can provide environment variables like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  myapp:
    image: your-image
    environment:
      - FOO=http://example.com
      - BAR=456
```

And depending on your application language, you can access to them. I.e for python:

```
import os
foo = os.environ.get("FOO")
bar = os.environ.get("BAR")
```

> Q. if I want to put it as dynamic whats need to be done , `- FOO=<dynamic value>`

You can do something like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  myapp:
    image: your-image
    environment:
      - FOO
      - BAR
```

Use as this:

```
$ export FOO=http://example.com
$ export BAR=456
$ docker-compose up
```

Comment: if I want to put it as dynamic whats need to be done ,
- FOO=<dynamic value>

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand you want your new image to accept an external URL as a parameter and then start processing on top of it. It can be done by writing a `bash` script as an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) script for the new image and the script will receive parameter value via [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

The `Dockerfile` will look something like:

```
FROM CURRENT_IMAGE
COPY custom-entrypoint.sh /root/
WORKDIR /root
ENTRYPOINT ["./custom-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Build the image and now launch the container using `docker run` you can pass your URL as a parameter and use that in script as `$1`. E.g:

```
docker run YOUR_IMAGE MY_URL
```

Comment: I am running my Docker image through docker-compose.yml, how I can add the external parameter from this file.

Comment: you can set an environment variable
 (https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) and use that in some script via docker-compose.yml as well.